# How to render entire DT table left justified on the page in Shiny?

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, render

Some of my DT tables seem to be centered on the page (see image 1 and 2 below). How can I make them aligned on the left so all tables and plots are aligned nicely.

[image: See the first table "Summary of Cluster Solutions", which is not left aligned on the page]

[image: Similarly, the table "Distribution of ...." is also not left aligned]

**My code to produce the 1st table ("Summary of Cluster Solutions")**

```
output$out_best <- DT::renderDataTable({
  #if (input$act_access_k >0) {
    DT::datatable(best_sols(), caption = "", rownames = TRUE,
      options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE,
      columnDefs = list(list(width = '100px', targets = 1)),
      paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE), selection='none') %>% formatRound(1:input$Bn, 3)
  #}
})
```

**My code to produce the 2nd table ("Distribution of...by clusters")**

```
output$prop_by_cluster <- DT::renderDataTable({
  if (input$act_next3 >0 & input$act_clust_sel>0) {
    DT::datatable(profile_result(), class= 'compact stripe', caption = '',
      rownames = F, options = list(autoWidth = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE,
      columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = 1)),
      paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE)) %>% formatPercentage(1: max(input$k)+2, 2)  
  }
})
```

**EDIT**

**BEFORE ADDING  style = "float:left"**

[image: BEFORE ADDING style = "float:left"]

**AFTER ADDING  style = "float:left"**

[image: AFTER ADDING style = "float:left"]

Comment: I tried a lot with `renderDataTable`; but could not find a way to align that from `server`. However, you can do it from `ui` as shown here: 
`mainPanel(style = "float:left", dataTableOutput("out_best"), dataTableOutput("prop_by_cluster "))`

Comment: Sagar - your suggestion works to align the tables on the left. However, the other table/plot seems to get smushed. See the images attached in my original post. Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Looks like your tables are all aligned left, but some of the columns are not justified properly. Need to align those.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the body of the page within the UI section.

ui.R:

tags$head(tags$style(".datatables .display {margin-left: 0;}"))

Comment: Would this be following the mainPanel() function or elsewhere in the UI?